# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET while loading angular application using nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

I have configured my nginx server as below. All my dist files are located at `/app/html/`. Say, the server name is `example.com` (where nginx is configured and angular 4 files are deployed). When I hit the server as `https://example.com:8443/` then everything works fine, the application is loaded.

Now, I have placed a load balancer on top of it and its url is `qc.example.com/testhtml`. When I hit `https://qc.example.com/testhtml` through browser then the application is not loaded and when I check the network in developer tools, it shows (failed) in status with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` as tooltip on it. Basically it does not load inline, pollyfills, scripts & main bundle js.

To my surprise, when I refresh the browser 4 to 5 times it start loading one by one on each refresh. I am not sure if it is a nginx issue or load balancer. Please help.

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    error_log  /app/log/nginx_error.log;
    root /app/testhtml;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /app/ssl/qc.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/ssl/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
 }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue after lot of research. I am posting the answer as this could help others to resolve there issue.

I have added another location for testhtml, set its root & declared index and it worked like a charm. Below are the changes

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    error_log  /app/log/nginx_error.log;
    root /app/testhtml;
    index index.html;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /app/ssl/qc.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/ssl/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /testhtml {
         root /app;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
 }}
```